# Sending SQL a boolean and update a table as 1 or -1 and how to "update" an empty row for the initial values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, if-statement, boolean

I have a `Songs` table with a `likes` column that holds the number of likes users sent . Each user sends a boolean (1 or 0) through a C# app which adds to the `likes` column.

About my procedure:

1. I want to know if there is more an efficient and short way of writing the part 1 of the function?
   I had to manually insert '0' instead of the `NULL` for the first time for the function to work. It wasn't working because the initial value for `Likes` column is `NULL`. Is there a way to affect the row for the first time when it has NULL in it?
2. For part 2 of the function with `[Users_Likes_Songs]` table, I want to update if the user send a like (true = 1) or removed it (false = 0).

   How can I update this table for the first time when  the users 'like' must be valued as '1', when its rows are completely empty?

I thank you very much if you can help me.

The procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Songs_Likes
    @User_ID INT,
    @SongID INT,
    @Song_like BIT
AS
BEGIN
    --- part 1 of the function
    IF (@Song_like = 1)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Songs] 
        SET [Likes] = [Likes] + @Song_like
        WHERE [Song_ID] = @SongID
    END

    IF (@Song_like = 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Songs] 
        SET [Likes] = [Likes] - 1
        WHERE [Song_ID] = @SongID
    END

    --- part 2 of the function with the second table
    UPDATE [Users_Likes_Songs]
    SET [LikeSong] = @Song_like 
    WHERE ([UserID] = @User_ID) AND ([SongID] = @SongID)
END
```

Comment: Why do you need to store the number of likes in the `Songs` table? You can always just calculate it from the `Users_Likes_Songs` table.

Comment: In regards to your comment B, why not set the `DEFAULT` value of `Likes` to 0, instead of `NULL`? Ideally, however, I would actually calculate the number on likes as a calculated value. Storing in table could quite easily end of with an incorrect value; especially with things like race conditions.

Comment: @HoneyBadger, its a good Idea, but for the demo project I have to insert 'fake' likes with no actual users.

Comment: @sup.DR I would say you cannot have likes without users, even for a demo. If you need to demo, create fake users, and have them like and dislike songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) this is a bit clearer, shorter and a bit more efficient.

```
UPDATE [Songs] 
    SET [Likes] = COALESCE([Likes], 0) + CASE WHEN @Song_like = 1 THEN 1
                                WHEN @Song_like = 0 THEN -1
                                ELSE 0 END
    WHERE [Song_ID] = @SongID;
```

For the second part you can do something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
    FROM [Users_Likes_Songs] 
    WHERE [UserID] = @User_ID 
    AND [SongID] = @SongID) 

  INSERT INTO [Users_Likes_Songs] (User_ID, SongID, [LikeSong]) 
    VALUES (@User_ID, @SongID, @Song_like)
ELSE
  UPDATE [Users_Likes_Songs]
    SET [LikeSong] = @Song_like WHERE ([UserID] = @User_ID) AND ([SongID] = @SongID)
```

Comment: I updated my second part of the question, can you please look at it ? I want to know if your I understand correctly your answer.

Comment: Thank you, just need to edit your answer with less ')' '(' as  -  `(SELECT 1 FROM [Users_Likes_Songs] WHERE [UserID] = @User_ID AND [SongID] = @SongID) `

Comment: Ah, yes... there were some confusing () and a missing ). Fixed in my response for future reference. Thanks for sharing !!!

Answer (score 3):

I think that the better method would be to change your design to calculate the likes and have a table that stores the likes for each user. In simple terms, something like:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE SCHEMA music;
GO

CREATE TABLE music.song (SongID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                         Artist nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
                         Title nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
                         ReleaseDate date);

CREATE TABLE music.[User] (UserID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                           [Login] nvarchar(128));

CREATE TABLE music.SongLike (LikeID bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
                             SongID int,
                             UserID int,
                             Liked bit);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UserLike ON music.SongLike(SongID, UserID); --Stops multiple likes
GO

--To add a LIKE you can then have a SP like:

CREATE PROC music.AddLike @SongID int, @UserID int, @Liked bit AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM music.SongLike WHERE UserID = @UserID AND SongID = @SongID) BEGIN
        UPDATE music.SongLike
        SET Liked = @Liked
        WHERE UserID = @UserID
          AND SongID = @SongID
    END ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO music.SongLike (SongID,
                                    UserID,
                                    Liked)
        VALUES (@SongID, @UserID, @Liked);
    END
END
GO

--And, if you want the number of likes:

CREATE VIEW music.SongLikes AS

    SELECT S.Artist,
           S.Title,
           S.ReleaseDate,
           COUNT(CASE SL.Liked WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS Likes
    FROM music.Song S
         JOIN music.SongLike SL ON S.SongID = SL.SongID
    GROUP BY S.Artist,
             S.Title,
             S.ReleaseDate;
GO
```

Comment: I would add a constraint (FK) for SongsLikes table reference the songID.

Comment: There are several indexes and constraints it needs, @Sami. This was just the bare basics. I'm not doing all the work for the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query in your procedure

```
UPDATE [songs] 
SET    [likes] = Isnull ([likes], 0) + ( CASE WHEN @Song_like THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) 
WHERE  [song_id] = @SongID
```

Comment: There is an erratum in your code: "ESLE" --> "ELSE". Also, COALESCE is more recommended than ISNULL as is ANSII standard